# Square bracket arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, square-bracket

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

So, I usually declare arrays using pointers.

However, you can also declare arrays using square brackets notation:

```
char a[] = "ok" ;
char b[] = "to" ;
char *pa = a ;

cout << "a " << sizeof( a ) << endl ;   // 3
cout << "pa " << sizeof( pa ) << endl ; // 4
```

The peculiar thing is, `sizeof( a )` will be the actual size of the array in bytes, and not the *size of a pointer*.

I find this odd, because where is the pointer then?  Is a square bracket-declared array actually a kind of datastructure with `(sizeof(char)*numElements)` bytes?

Also, you cannot re-assign a to b:

```
a = b ; // ILLEGAL.
```

Why is that?  It seems as though a **is the array** and not a pointer to the array (*"left operand must be l-value"* is the error for `a = b` above).  Is that right?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957 Maybe not, because the confusion here perhaps is caused by the `char a[]` notation. @bobobobo, do you know that you can declare an array like `char a[3]`, and that will also be an actual array object, not a pointer? The empty brackets are just a shorthand because programmers can't count - `char a[] = "ok";` means the same as `char a[3] = "ok";`

Comment: I'd advocate using std::array in c++ if it is available to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is that? It seems as though a is the array and not a pointer to the array ("left operand must be l-value" is the error for a = b above).

`a` is indeed an array type and not a pointer type.
You cannot assign to an array because it is a *non-modifiable* lvalue.

BTW Array decays to pointer to the first element when it is passed to a function.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the square brackets in your declaration, you are actually allocating space on the stack. When you use the `*` to declare a pointer, you are simply declaring a pointer. So

`char a[] = "ok";`

will actually allocate 3 bytes on the stack, and fill it with the string `ok\0`. However if you do

`char a* = "ok";`

it will allocate enough room for a pointer, and set the pointer to a location in the data section containing the string `ok\0` (i.e. it's compiled in as a constant).

Answer (score 0):

Correct, the type of `a` is char array of length 3. Array variables can be assigned to pointer variables because array types can decay into a pointer to the first element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's a *constant* pointer to the first (zeroth) element in the array.

Check out the "Pointers and Arrays" section [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/)